# is it possible to combine react-native with traditional swift views?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I would like to use RazzleDazzle along with react-native. I know you can create 'bindings' for components but I was thinking it would be cool to have an intro screen made with https://github.com/IFTTT/RazzleDazzle that would then transition into the react-native app.

So my question is, is it possible to combine react-native with native ios Swift views?